# bash select type word not number

Tags: bash, select, interactive

I am using bash select to produce an interactive menu, so a code like this:

```
select CHOISE in "${ARRAY_OF_DIRS[@]}"; do
myfolder=$CHOISE
echo "you have selected: $myfolder"
done
```

will produce this output:

```
1) Desktop
2) Documents
3) Downloads
...
```

If you hit something like '3' the script will reply:

```
you have selected: Downloads
```

My question is this: Is there a way to make the script accept ID numbers *and* the literal answer? So the user can type 'Downloads' in stead of '3'? If you cannot do this with select, do you have any recommendations as to how this script can be rewritten to incorporate such functionality?

Thanks in advance for any help on this :)

Comment: How you want distinguish if you got a folder with a name "2", so the select will print `1) "2" 2) "Desktop"` - if someone enters "2" - what should it mean - a folder with name "2" or the _second_ choice?

Comment: Good question! If select has a variable that holds the input it could be theoretically possible to make some logic that checks for this..?

Comment: It __is__ theoretically possible - but (imho) you should eliminating the duality and stick only with the numbered choices...

Comment: You mark a question as solved by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer that solved it. Do not put “Solved” in the title, that does not mark the question as solved in the UI. If no answer solved the question, add your own answer. You can check your own answers, in fact there is a participation badge for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

You want to look at the `$REPLY` variable in addition to `$CHOISE`:

```
ARRAY_OF_DIRS=( Desktop Documents Downloads "dir with spaces" )

select CHOISE in "${ARRAY_OF_DIRS[@]}"; do 
    echo "REPLY => $REPLY, CHOISE => $CHOISE"
    myfolder=${CHOISE:-$REPLY}
    echo "you have selected: $myfolder"
done
```

REPLY is the actual text the user typed at the select prompt.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-select

---

You'll probably want to do a little more validation:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=":" 
select CHOISE in "${ARRAY_OF_DIRS[@]}"; do  
    unset myfolder
    if [[ -n $CHOISE ]]; then 
        # user selected a "menu number"
        myfolder=$CHOISE
    elif [[ "$IFS${ARRAY_OF_DIRS[*]}$IFS" == *"$IFS$REPLY$IFS"* ]]; then
        # user typed in a value
        myfolder=$REPLY
    fi
    [[ -n $myfolder ]] &&
        echo "you have selected: $myfolder" ||
        echo "invalid selection: '$REPLY'"
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```